# NLua: Unable to cast object of type 'Command[]' to type 'System.Object[]'

Tags: c#, arrays, enums, monogame, nlua

I have a game engine that uses NLua for scripting. However, I can't seem to access elements in my `Command` array:

```
-- Basic direction detection. This allows forward and backward to cancel each other out if both are active.
function DetectXHoldDirection()
    directionDetect = 0
    if self.MainBuffer.Hold[0].Directions:HasFlag(Direction.Forward) then
        directionDetect = directionDetect + 1
    end
    if self.MainBuffer.Hold[0].Directions:HasFlag(Direction.Back) then
        directionDetect = directionDetect - 1
    end
end
```

`MainBuffer` is an object of type `BufferedCommand`, which contains arrays of `Command` structs, called "Hold," "Release," and "Press." The `Command` struct contains two enum properties, Buttons, of type `Button` (a flags enum), and `Directions` of type `Direction` (another flags enum).

When I try running this script, I get the error in the title. Why is it trying to cast to `System.Object[]`? Is there any way to get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to a hint from [LuaInterface docs](http://www.luteus.biz/Download/LoriotPro_Doc/LUA/LUA_For_Windows/luainterface/LuaInterface.html#T5), which I believe was the basis for NLua.

Apparently you cannot access arrays in this way in NLua. It's quite annoying, but you have to use the `Array.GetValue()` method like so:

```
-- Basic direction detection. This allows forward and backward to cancel each other out if both are active.
function DetectXHoldDirection()
    directionDetect = 0
    if self.MainBuffer.Hold:GetValue(0).Directions:HasFlag(Direction.Forward) then
        directionDetect = directionDetect + 1
    end
    if self.MainBuffer.Hold:GetValue(0).Directions:HasFlag(Direction.Back) then
        directionDetect = directionDetect - 1
    end
end
```

Again, I don't like this, but if anyone has any way of converting this to proper array indexing, I'd love to know! But for now, this does what I want.